# Serverless deploy on AWS - routes brakes

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless

I'm deploing my first nodejs serverless app on AWS. In local stage all work well, but when I try to access to my app on AWS, all the routes are brakes. The endpoint serving from the cli is like this:

> https://test.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/stage/

adding the word ***stage*** at the end of the path. So all my routes to static resources or other endpoint are brakes.

This is my config file:

secret.json

```
{
  "NODE_ENV": "stage",
  "SECRET_OR_KEY": "secret",
  "TABLE_NAME": "table",
  "service_URL": "https://services_external/json",
  "DATEX_USERNAME": "usrn",
  "DATEX_PASSWD": "psw"
}
```

serverless.yml

```
service: sls-express-dynamodb

custom:
  iopipeNoVerify: true
  iopipeNoUpgrade: true
  iopipeNoStats: true
  secrets: ${file(secrets.json)}

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: ${self:custom.secrets.NODE_ENV}
  region: eu-west-1
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${self:custom.secrets.NODE_ENV}
    SECRET_OR_KEY: ${self:custom.secrets.SECRET_OR_KEY}
    TABLE_NAME: ${self:custom.secrets.TABLE_NAME}
    DATEX_USERNAME: ${self:custom.secrets.DATEX_USERNAME}
    DATEX_PASSWD: ${self:custom.secrets.DATEX_PASSWD}
    DATEX_URL: ${self:custom.secrets.DATEX_URL}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        - dynamodb:Query
        # - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: 'arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.TABLE_NAME}'

functions:
  app:
    handler: server.run
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: ANY
          cors: true
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find out the API Gateway endpoint via Web UI.

- Login into the AWS Console
- Go to **API Gateway**
- On the left panel, click on the API name. (E.g. sls-express-dynamodb-master)
- On the left panel, click on **Stages**
- On the middle panel, click on the stage name. (E.g. master)
- On the right panel you will find the API URL, marked as: **Invoke URL**